# What’s the best way to shuffle an array in Perl?

Tags: perl, random, shuffle

So I have a file. Let’s say it looks like this (it's actually longer):

```
1234
2134
3124
4123
```

What is the best way to shuffle the lines in that file?

Comment: what do u mean by randomly looping?

Comment: I think he means shuffle, right Bill ?

Comment: @sputnick Yes, That's what i mean

Comment: The Perl FAQ covers this, as well as many other common Perl questions: [How do I shuffle an array randomly?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-shuffle-an-array-randomly?)

Comment: Besides the FAQ which @Andy kindly points out, there are [40 Perl questions that mention “shuffle”](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bperl%5D+shuffle) that you should probably study.

Comment: @tchrist I change the title to shuffle after I found my solution (to help others find it, on suggestion of @sputnick)... I had no idea 'shuffle' existed. I had something like "What's the best way to randomize an array". Are you just pointing out that there are lots of questions about shuffle or do you really think I need to read those other questions?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw/shuffle/;

my @arr = shuffle <>;

print @arr;
```

Usage :

```
./script file.txt
```

Comment: List::Util is a core module, if that's important to you. (It is to me. I am a module snob.)